# Why is 'Count Points in Polygon' returning zero values for all NUMPOINTS?

Tags: qgis-3, vector-grid, point-in-polygon

I'm using QGIS and I have a file of points (Coyote_Clipped).  I'm trying to count the number of points in each grid cell. I ran "Count Points in Polygon" on the grid and it worked without errors, but when I look at the attribute table for the count shapefile the value is zero for all NUMPOINTS, even though there are clearly points that fall inside the grid cells.  What might be happening here?

This is the file I'm working with:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dNiUPOhNNqFHrJ3dpZ0zHi95Vn3D1iIx/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use the same projection on both layers?

Comment: Yes, they're the same.

Comment: Did you restart QGIS (probably your machine as well) and give another try? Are you sure to have selected the right layers (grid, points)? You did not activate `Selected features only` by accident? If you repeat it with all this in mind: does the problem persist?